# Looking for maximum/minimum value in JSON

Tags: java, json

I am trying to query this JSON from this URL (https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json) to search through and return the name of the item (Cannonball is the first name in the JSON for example) that has the maximum/minimum value in one of the other categories (buy_quantity for example).

EDIT: With help from @meriton my code is now

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try{

        Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem> exchangeSummary = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"), new TypeReference<Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem>>() {});
        System.out.println(exchangeSummary.size());
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Although, I can't seem to figure out how to search through exchangeSummary and find certain values, the item with the highest buy_quantity for example.

Comment: This would be easier in JavaScript (less than half the code, I reckon). Are you sure you want to do it in Java?

Comment: @PaulRooney I want to deal with all of it unfortunately.

Comment: @meriton I have a little bit of experience with java but none in javascript

Comment: @PaulRooney: If you open the url in firefox, it will show the JSON object in an expandable tree view, which makes it very easy to see its structure. In Chrome, you can achieve the same effect by opening the developer tools, go to the network tab, and check the "preview" of the response.

Comment: @meriton fair enough, I withdrew my comment a while back. But a simple example like [this](https://pastebin.com/ypzdRFqV) make it easy to know what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing JSON in Java, one usually uses a databinding library that copies the JSON data into ordinary java objects.

To do that, we need to write a Java class to accept the JSON data. Looking at your JSON, it appears to be contain an object with dynamic properties that map each id to an object describing that market item. On the Java side, we can represent this with a `Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem>`, where `ExchangeSummaryItem` is defined by

```
public class ExchangeSummaryItem {
    public String id;
    public String name;
    public boolean members;
    public int sp;
    public int buy_average;
    public int but_quantity;
    public int sell_average;
    public int sell_quantity;
    public int overall_average;
    public int overall_quantity;
}
```

With this definition, we can ask a databinding library such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/) to read the JSON data into objects of this class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem> exchangeSummary = mapper.readValue(
    new URL("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json"), 
    new TypeReference<Map<String, ExchangeSummaryItem>>() {}
);
```

And then you can simply iterate over the collection, and do whatever you want with the item data:

```
for (ExchangeSummaryItem item : exchangeSummary.values()) {
  // do whatever you want with item
}
```

For more information on Jackson, check out their docs, in particular their [README](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/).

Comment: Just want to add to your answer `ArrayNode arrayNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();for (ExchangeSummaryItem item : exchangeSummary.values()) {
            arrayNode.addPOJO(item);
        }`

Comment: This can be added to mongoDb and can be used for multiple queries. like `db.getCollection('collection-name').find({}).sort({"buy_quantity":-1})`

Comment: @meriton Thanks for the awesome answer! I'm trying it out right now, and it seems to be having issues with the readValue, does this come from a certain library? If not then I'm not too sure what my issue is... This is the error I am getting `The method readValue(URL, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (URL, new TypeReference<Map<String,ExchangeSummaryItem>>(){})` I was using a different import for TypeReference that was causing another issue but when I changed it I believe that was fixed.

Comment: That's odd, because `readValue(URL, TypeReference<T>)` does exist: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1332

Comment: @meriton What version of Jackson are you using? Throughout this project I have messed around with a bunch of them so maybe that messed something up

Comment: According to [the git history of the Jackson project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blame/f82000a20c6b1a1cb2450f82748596f8ee6999b4/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1405), this method was added 7 years ago ... are you sure you are using correct argument types? You should be using `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`.

Comment: @meriton That was the import I was using originally but another post said I should try a codehaus one but I've switched back now and the error is gone. But now when I run the program I get a nasty looking error`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView`

Comment: Quoting the Jackson README I linked: "Since package also depends on jackson-core and jackson-annotations packages, you will need to download these if not using Maven".

Comment: @meriton Thanks so much for all the help so far, It would have taken me forever to figure all this out. Everything up to the second code block you posted in your original reply is now working, although I'm a bit confused how to use the for loop to query. How would I return the name for the object with the highest buy_quantity for example?